# UnderscoreJS - Merge multiple arrays into one

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have four arrays as shown below:

```
var array1 = [['dept', 'dept1'], ['empl', 'empl1'], ['month', 'Jan']];
var array2 = [['dept', 'dept2'], ['empl', 'empl2'], ['month', 'Feb']];
var array3 = [['dept', 'dept3'], ['empl', 'empl3'], ['month', 'March']];
var array4 = [['dept', 'dept4'], ['empl', 'empl4'], ['month', 'April']];
```

And using `Underscore.js`, I want to merge them to reproduce result array as:

```
var resultArray = [
  ['dept', 'dept1', 'dept2', 'dept3', 'dept4'], 
  ['empl', 'empl1', 'empl2', 'empl3', 'empl4'], 
  ['month', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April']
];
```

So here first element of each nested array is **Key**.

I tried using `_.zip` but it reproduces separate array.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spidercode/d4gogeof/) for the same.

**Edit**

It could be possible that some element is missing in one of the array. For example:

```
var array1 = [['dept', 'dept1'], ['empl', 'empl1'], ['month', 'Jan']];
var array2 = [['empl', 'empl2'], ['month', 'Feb']];
var array3 = [['dept', 'dept3'], ['month', 'March']];
var array4 = [['dept', 'dept4'], ['empl', 'empl4']];
```

Comment: are the arrays always of the same length and in same order?

Comment: _.map(_.zip(array1, array2, array3), function(row) {
        var o = {};
        o[row[0].in_id] = _.pluck(row, "keyHere");
        return o;
    });

Comment: Try above and let us know.

Comment: @Imran : what to put as a Key in this sample ?

Comment: @AbhishekAnand : No it is not necessary. It might be possible some element is missing. For example in Arrray2 we might not have have a `dept`. But sub array would always be a length of two

Comment: you should just use Object. you are using array to do what objects are supposed to

Comment: @AbhishekAnand : I know that. It is bad design. But I am in a situation that if i change design, i would have lot of work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const result = [], position = {};

 for(const array of [array1, array2, array3, array4]){
   for(const [key, value] of array){
      if(key in position){
        result[ position[key] ].push(value);
      } else {
        position[key] = result.push([key, value]) - 1;
      }
   }
 }
```

This uses a hashtable to store the keys position. When the key was not used already, it pushes a new array to the result  including the key and the value, if the array exists already it just pushes the value to the array under that position. Note that this is `O(n)` were `n` is the number of key-value pairs.

---

If you want a sparse array instead:

```
 const result = [], position = {};

 for(const [index, array] of [array1, array2, array3, array4].entries()){
   for(const [key, value] of array){
      if(!(key in position))
        position[key] = result.push([key]) - 1;
      result[ position[key] ][index + 1] = value;            
   }
 }
```

Comment: This reproduce array like:  `["dept", "dept1", "dept", "dept2", "dept", "dept3", "dept", "dept4"]`

Comment: [Try it!](https://tio.run/##ZZDPjoMgEMbvPsWkFzWxTfxzMz3sZQ@b7BMQDqzFLbtUDKBJ0/jsLghrq3BgYOb7fjOZHzIS1UjW62MnLnSeRyKBSEnuOZwBofhCex1nsMQ8xhmgmN56blM2@tRNdPpqcx@kizGuoxVThJgixBQ7zDv92mLKEFOGmHKH@SSyuW5BVQiqQlC1A731kvEFFEWN6JQGSdXAtYUZZS8U00x05vuYjAZaIROnW5qCaAG5rWZ@LT6WPlY4fUQAL0b0S@8ZjIQPFFv/InMic1ibmDqwbu29lsDPhtaSRWHAp35Q12QhprUXT0C5ovD0bj1nz3LW15FSOEK@UiJ3TW47gtMTF9/J4R92eK7IdN5qXAOjcI@0nuc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine your arrays into a single array, then using `array#reduce` and `array#forEach` you can merge them using the first value of each array.

```js
var array1 = [['dept', 'dept1'], ['empl', 'empl1'], ['month', 'Jan']];
var array2 = [['empl', 'empl2'], ['month', 'Feb']];
var array3 = [['dept', 'dept3'], ['month', 'March']];
var array4 = [['dept', 'dept4'], ['empl', 'empl4']];
var combined = []
combined.push(array1, array2, array3, array4);
var result = Object.values(combined.reduce((r,a) => {
   a.forEach(([name, value]) => {
    r[name] = r[name] || [name];
    r[name].push(value);
   });
   return r;
 }, {}))
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It is working great. But it could be possible that some elements are missing in any of the array. I have edited question.

Comment: Updated the solution, you can merge your array on the first value of each array.

Comment: Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need Underscore JS for that ?

//INPUT

```
var array1 = [['dept', 'dept1'], ['empl', 'empl1'], ['month', 'Jan']];
var array2 = [['dept', 'dept2'], ['empl', 'empl2'], ['month', 'Feb']];
var array3 = [['dept', 'dept3'], ['empl', 'empl3'], ['month', 'March']];
var array4 = [['dept', 'dept4'], ['empl', 'empl4'], ['month', 'April']];
```

//Direct way

```
var resultArray = [
Array.from(new set([...array1[0],...array2[0],...array3[0],...array4[0]])),
Array.from(new Set([...array1[1],...array2[1],...array3[1],...array4[1]])),
Array.from(new Set([...array1[2],...array2[2],...array3[2],...array4[2]]))];
```

//Looping

```
var resultArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i <3; i++){
    resultArray.push(Array.from(new Set([...array1[i],...array2[i],...array3[i],...array4[i]])));
}
```

//Result

```
[
  ['dept', 'dept1', 'dept2', 'dept3', 'dept4'], 
  ['empl', 'empl1', 'empl2', 'empl3', 'empl4'], 
  ['month', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'March', 'April']
]
```